# can the second parameter of assertTrue in junit be a string?

Tags: java, junit, assert

I see the following junit code:

```
public class Student {
    String name;

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
}
```

in Junit there is a testcase:

```
public void testName()
{
        Student student;
        assertTrue("can not get the info" + student.getName(), student.getName());
}
```

based on the API of `assertTrue(java.lang.String message, boolean condition)`, the second parameter of assertTrue is boolean, but why `student.getName()` can be used as second parameter of `assertTrue`?

Comment: Is your testcase working??

Comment: Your code won't compile.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `assertEquals()` for that kind of scenario.

```
assertEquals("your result","expected result");
```

Answer (score 2):

Test unit means test "**observed versus expected**" you need an expected value, then

```
assertTrue("can not get the info" + student.getName(), student.getName().equals("expected value"));
```

or better (as sugested by Ruchira +1)

```
assertEquals(student.getName(),"expected value")
```

which is `NullPointerException` safe

Answer (score 1):

you have used '+' sign(java string concatenation operator) that appends the result of student.getName() to the existing string. so it is okay. there are a string and a boolean argument.

Comment: student.getName() returns string--not boolean , compilation error

Comment: but <"...." + student.getname() > this part is a string. and the last argument is boolean. you could have used only student.getName() without the initial string "can not get the info".please try.

Comment: Code clearly says that student.getName() returns string

Comment: assertTrue takes two args one string and one boolean. student.getName() generates string. please use equalsIgnorecase("expected value"). it returns true/false - boolean value.